# JavaFx:an error while adding a like on my post

Tags: java, sql, javafx, crud

I tried to add a like when pressing **Like** button. I've used a simple add code (I'm pasting it below) but I keep getting errors:

```
Apr 06, 2018 10:30:08 AM Service.LikeService addlike
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like (blog,user) values (1,'aaa')' at line 1
null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
nom
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at Service.LikeService.addlike(LikeService.java:146)
    at Controller.CommentaireController.LikeAction(CommentaireController.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

I'm using MVC architecture, here's my LikeService:

```
package Service;

import Model.like;
import Util.Connexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public  class LikeService  {
private  Connection con;
private Statement ste;
private PreparedStatement pst;

    public LikeService() {
        con=Connexion.getInstance().getConnection();
    }
    public void add1(like t, int id_pub) {
        try{
           //System.out.println(t.getCom_created());
               Statement st = con.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate("insert into like(blog,user) values('"+id_pub+"','"+t.getUser()+"')");


           }catch(SQLException ex){
               System.out.println(ex);
           }
    }
    /* public String afficher(int id_pub){
        try{
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from jaime where id_pub = "+id_pub+" ");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        int var=rs.getInt(1);
            return Integer.toString(var);
        }

        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CommentaireDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
         return "0"; 
    }*/
    public int displayAllById(int i) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

  List<Integer> list =new ArrayList();
        try{
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from like where blog="+i+" ");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                //créer une instance vide de personne()

                list.add(rs.getInt(1));
                //afficher l'instane 
                //System.out.println(l);

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CommentaireService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
             System.out.println(list);
        return list.size();


    }

    /*

     public int liked(int i,String j) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

  List<Integer> list =new ArrayList();
        try{
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from like where blog="+i+" and user="+j+" ");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                //créer une instance vide de personne()

                list.add(rs.getInt(1));
                //afficher l'instane 
                //System.out.println(l);

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CommentaireService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
             System.out.println(list);
        return list.size();


    }*/
    /*
    public int plusjaime() {
        // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

  List<Integer> list =new ArrayList();
         try{
  pst = con.prepareStatement("select  like.blog from like inner join forum on like.blog=forum.id where extract(month from forum.Cree)=extract(month from curdate()) group by id_pub limit 1");
             ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

             while(rs.next()){

                 list.add(rs.getInt(1));


             }

         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(PublicationDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }    

     return list.get(0);


    }
     */

    public void addlike(like p) {
        String rq = "insert into like (blog,user) values (?,?);";
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(rq);

            pst.setInt(1, p.getBlog());
            pst.setString(2, p.getUser());


            pst.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LikeService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    }
/*
    @Override
    public void update(jaime t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(jaime t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public List<jaime> displayAll() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public jaime findById(jaime t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void add(jaime t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
*/
```

Also my controller:

```
package Controller;

import static Controller.ForumController.a;
import static Controller.ForumController.cr;
import static Controller.ForumController.j;
import static Controller.ForumController.l;
import static Controller.ForumController.t;
import static Controller.LoginController.LoggedUser;
import Model.Commentaire;
import Model.Forum;
import Model.like;
import Service.CommentaireService;
import Service.ForumService;
import Service.LikeService;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author nessrine
 */
public class CommentaireController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label id; 
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listcom;
    List< Commentaire> list2 = new ArrayList<Commentaire>();
    @FXML
    private JFXButton Ajouter1;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton Ajouter11;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField commentaire;
       like likee = new like(); 
    @FXML
    private JFXButton commenter;
 Commentaire com=new Commentaire();
         CommentaireService su=new CommentaireService();
         LikeService li=new LikeService();

    @FXML
    private JFXButton modifier;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton supprimer;
     public static int i;
             public static String testpersonne;
              List<String> listPersonne = new ArrayList< String>();
    @FXML
    private Label titre;
    @FXML
    private Label auteur;
    @FXML
    private Label date;
    @FXML
    private Label contenu;
    @FXML
    private Label tag;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton like;
    @FXML
    private Label likes;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       afficherID();
       affichageInterface();
       supprimer.setDisable(true);
       modifier.setDisable(true);
       /*int nbr = li.liked(j, LoggedUser.username) ;
        if (nbr < 1) {
        like.setDisable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            like.setDisable(true);
        }*/

    }
    public boolean controleSaisie() {
        if (commentaire.getText().isEmpty() ) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Required fields");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Please fill in all fields");
            alert.show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


     public void afficherID()
     {
         id.setText(String.valueOf(l));
         titre.setText(String.valueOf(t));
         auteur.setText(String.valueOf(a));
         contenu.setText(String.valueOf(cr));
         tag.setText(String.valueOf(cr));

     }


    public void affichageInterface() {

         CommentaireService su=new CommentaireService();

        list2 = su.displayAllById(l);

        ObservableList<String> itemss = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
//                    System.out.println(list2.get(i).getContenu());
            listPersonne.add(list2.get(i).getUser());
            System.out.println(su.displayAllUser(list2.get(i).getUser()).getNom());
            itemss.add("Le membre: "+ su.displayAllUser(list2.get(i).getUser()).getNom() + " " + su.displayAllUser(list2.get(i).getUser()).getPrenom() +" a commenté : "
                    + list2.get(i).getCommentaire());
        }
        listcom.setItems(itemss);
    }

    @FXML
    private void AjouterSujetLink(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent list_page_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/AddForum.fxml"));
        Scene list_page_scene = new Scene(list_page_parent);
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

                app_stage.hide(); //optional
                app_stage.setScene(list_page_scene);
                app_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void AfficherSujet(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            Parent list_page_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/Forum.fxml"));
        Scene list_page_scene = new Scene(list_page_parent);
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

                app_stage.hide(); //optional
                app_stage.setScene(list_page_scene);
                app_stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void commenter(ActionEvent event) {

       if (controleSaisie()) {
        com.setCommentaire(commentaire.getText());
        com.setBlog(l);
        com.setUser(LoggedUser.username);
        su.add(com);
        affichageInterface();
       }
    }

    @FXML
    private void modifier(ActionEvent event) {

          su.update1(list2.get(i).getId(), commentaire.getText());
        affichageInterface();
        System.out.println("Modification avec succes ");

    }

    @FXML
    private void supprimer(ActionEvent event) {

            su.deletebyid(list2.get(i).getId());

        affichageInterface();
        System.out.println("Supprimer avec succes ");
    }

    @FXML
    private void listCom_Clicked(MouseEvent event) {
           i = listcom.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            testpersonne = listPersonne.get(i);
        if (testpersonne.equals(LoggedUser.username) ) {
            supprimer.setDisable(false);
        } else {
            supprimer.setDisable(true);

        }
        if (testpersonne.equals(LoggedUser.username)) {
            modifier.setDisable(false);
        } else {
            modifier.setDisable(true);

        }

       commentaire.setText(list2.get(i).getCommentaire());

    }

    @FXML
    private void LikeAction(ActionEvent event) {

        like lik = new like(1, LoggedUser.username);

         li.addlike(lik);

        affichageInterface();
       /* affichagelike();
        System.out.println("ajouter");
        int nbr = li.liked(1, LoggedUser.username) ;
        if (nbr < 1) {
        like.setDisable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            like.setDisable(true);
        }*/
    }

    @FXML
    private void affichagelike() {

        int k;
        k= li.displayAllById(j);
        System.out.println(k);

        likes.setText(Integer.toString(k) +" "+" j'aime");

    }
    }
```

This is how my fxml and the button look like:

[image]

Comment: 'like' is a sql reserved word, rename your table into another name

Comment: You may want to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NisrineHafi Pidev ?